# Remove Last element from a Character Array in Android?

Tags: android, arrays

**What i Have:**  At present i have a String variable i-e:

```
String str_StoreValue;
```

I have appended it with some string values and converted it into a Character Array by doing this:

```
char[] ch_TestArray = str_StoreValue.toCharArray();
```

**What i want:**  i want to remove the last element of this `char[] ch_TestArray`.

Can somebody help me out.  I'm new to android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just easier:

```
char[] ch_TestArray = str_StoreValue.substring(0, str_StoreValue.length()-1).toCharArray();
```

Comment: in case i have some issue again i can directly ask u :)
i am new to android.

Comment: You should ask it here. i may be online but not have time to answer your question. If you ask here, someone who has time will answer

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3999/discussion-between-noman-and-las-vegas)

Comment: Plus if you ask it in a public place such as this other people have the chance to benefit from it later on down the line they have a similar question and find SO from their searches.